# Custom unaccent rules in heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, unaccent

We have an application running in heroku and we want to add a search feature on a field that contains greek characters and we want to make it accent agnostic.

So the idea is to use postgresql's [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html) functionality. The problem is that by default greek rules are not included at heroku and we somehow need to add them (we already have a rules file).

Has anyone managed to add custom rules files at heroku, and if yes could you please share how?

Comment: I did this for an app in Irish. If the functionality you want is not natively available, use a "shadow column". We wanted to search via surnames and Irish rules are much more complicated than English. Throw in accents and it's horrendeous. We had an OnInsert `TRIGGER` whereby we inserted any names entered into a column called "search_name" (the shadow column). We removed accents from, capitalised and removed spaces from the name input string. Input and display on human typed input, searching on the shadow. Worked a treat!

Comment: So you manually removed accents or did you use `unaccent`? My problem here is how to add extra rules in `unaccent` command to support greek.

Comment: We used something like (if in_char == 'á' then in_char = 'a') - there are only acute accents in Irish - not sure about Greek, but it has the advantage of only having to be done once - on  insert and then searches incur no penalty! The important thing is to have the function in only one place - if you have bugs, they only need to be repaired once.

Comment: What you did is one way to go. unaccent function provides that functionality by simply providing rules about how to "translate" a letter. Follow the link in my question above to read more about it, you will like it :)

Comment: Are you saying that you have created a Greek rules file? If so, that sounds like the way to go - daxi! As I mentioned, we took our approach because the functionality wasn't native! Maybe I'll write this up as an answer for the generic case?

Comment: You can but in general it will be out of scope. The scope of the question is how to add the custom rules file to heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Heroku after trying to find a solution for the exact same issue. Here is the response:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to upload that unaccent.rules file to
>   the Postgres server that hosts your database. You can enable the
>   unaccent extension, but not supply a custom rules files. If this is a
>   requirement for your app to run, you will unfortunately have to find a
>   workaround that doesn't rely on the unaccent.rules file.

So the shadow column might be the way to go for heroku after all.